# Memory Consistency Errors vs Thread interference

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

What is the difference between memory consistency errors and thread interference?
How does the use of synchronization to avoid them differ or not? Please illustrate with an example. I couldn't get this from the sun Java tutorial. Any recommendation of reading material(s) to understand this purely in context of java would be helpful.

Answer (score 16):

**Memory consistency errors** can't be understood purely in the context of java--the details of shared memory behavior on multi-cpu systems are highly architecture-specific, and to make it worse, x86 (where most people coding today learned to code) has pretty programmer-friendly semantics compared to architectures that were designed for multi-processor machines from the beginning (like POWER and SPARC), so most people really aren't used to thinking about memory access semantics.

I'll give a common example of where memory consistency errors can get you into trouble. Assume for this example, that the initial value of `x` is 3. Nearly all architectures guarantee that if one CPU executes the code:

```
STORE 4 -> x     // x is a memory address
STORE 5 -> x
```

and another CPU executes

```
LOAD x
LOAD x
```

will either see `3,3`, `3,4`, `4,4`, `4,5`, or `5,5` from the perspective its two `LOAD` instructions. Basically, CPUs guarantee that the order of writes to a single memory location is maintained from the perspective of all CPUs, even if the exact time that each of the writes become known to other CPUs is allowed to vary.

Where CPUs differ from one another tends to be in the guarantees they make about `LOAD` and `STORE` operations involving different memory addresses. Assume for this example, that the initial values of both `x` and `y` are 4.

```
STORE 5 -> x   // x is a memory address
STORE 5 -> y // y is a different memory address
```

then another CPU executes

```
LOAD x
LOAD y
```

In this example, on some architectures, the second thread can see `4,4`, `5,5`, `4,5`, OR `5,4`. Ouch!

Most architectures deal with memory at the granularity of a 32 or 64 bit word--this means that on a 32 bit POWER/SPARC machine, you can't update a 64-bit integer memory location and safely read it from another thread *ever* without explicit synchronization. Goofy, huh?

**Thread interference** is much simpler. The basic idea is that java doesn't guarantee that a single statement of java code executes atomically. For example, incrementing a value requires reading the value, incrementing it, then storing it again. So you can have `int x = 1` after two threads  execute `x++`, `x` can end up as `2` or `3` depending on how the lower-level code interleaved (the lower-level abstract code at work here presumably looks like `LOAD x, INCREMENT, STORE x`). The basic idea here is that java code is broken down into smaller atomic pieces and you don't get to make assumptions of how they interleave unless you use synchronization primitives explicitly.

**For more information**, check out [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20150126124619/http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.91.957&rep=rep1&type=pdf) paper. It's long and dry and written by a notorious asshole, but hey, it's pretty good too. Also check out [this](http://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Epugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html) (or just google for "double checked locking is broken"). These memory reordering issues reared their ugly heads for many C++/java programmers who tried to get a little bit too clever with their singleton initializations a few years ago.

Answer (score 5):

Thread interference is about threads overwriting each other's statements (say, thread A incrementing a counter and thread B decrementing it *at the same time*), leading to a situation where the actual value of counter is unpredictable. You avoid them by enforcing exclusive access, one thread at a time.

On the other hand, memory inconsistency is about visibility. Thread A may increment `counter`, but then thread B may not be aware of this change *yet* so it might read some prior value. You avoid them by establishing a happens-before relationship, which is

> is simply a guarantee that memory writes by one specific statement are visible to another specific statement.(per [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html))

Answer (score 2):

The article to read on this is "Memory Models: A Case for Rethinking Parallel Languages and Hardware" by Adve and Boehm in the August 2010 vol. 53 number 8 issue of Communications of the ACM.  This is available online for Association for Computer Machinery members (http://www.acm.org).  This deals with the problem in general and also discusses the Java Memory Model.

For more information on the Java Memory Model, see http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/

Answer (score 1):

**1. Thread Interference**

```
class Counter {
    private int c = 0;

    public void increment() {
        c++;
    }

    public void decrement() {
        c--;
    }

    public int value() {
        return c;
    }

}
```

> Suppose there are two threads Thread-A and Thread-B working on the
>   same counter instance  . Say Thread-A invokes increment() , and at the
>   same time Thread-B invokes decrement() . Thread-A reads the value c
>   and  increment it by 1 . At the same time Thread-B reads the value (
>   which is 0 because the incremented value is not yet set by Thread-A) ,
>   decrements it and set it to -1 . Now Thread-A sets the value to 1 .

**2. Memory Consistency Errors**

> Memory Consistency Errors occurs when different threads have
>   inconsistent views of the shared data.  In the above class counter ,
>   Lets say there are two threads working on the same counter instance , 
>   calls the increment method to increase the counter's value by 1 . Here
>   it is no guarantee that the changes made by one thread is visible to
>   the other .

For more visit [this](http://javasolutionsonline.blogspot.com/2013/09/thread-interference-and-memory.html).

Answer (score 0):

Memory Consistency problems are normally manifest as broken happens-before relationships.

```
Time A: Thread 1 sets int i = 1
Time B: Thread 2 sets i = 2
Time C: Thread 1 reads i, but still sees a value of 1, because of any number of reasons that it did not get the most recent stored value in memory.
```

You prevent this from happening either by using the `volatile` keyword on the variable, or by using the AtomicX classes from the `java.util.concurrent.atomic` package.  Either of these messages makes sure that no second thread will see a partially modified value, and no one will ever see a value that isn't the most current real value in memory.

(Synchronizing the getter and setter would also fix the problem, but may look strange to other programmers who don't know why you did it, and can also break down in the face of things like binding frameworks and persistence frameworks that use reflection.)

--

Thread interleaves are when two threads munge an object up and see inconsistent states.

We have a PurchaseOrder object with an itemQuantity and itemPrice, automatic logic generates the invoice total.

```
Time 0: Thread 1 sets itemQuantity 50
Time 1: Thread 2 sets itemQuantity 100
Time 2: Thread 1 sets itemPrice 2.50, invoice total is calculated $250
Time 3: Thread 2 sets itemPrice 3, invoice total is calculated at $300
```

Thread 1 performed an incorrect calculation because some other thread was messing with the object in between his operations.

You address this issue either by using the `synchronized` keyword, to make sure only one person can perform the entire process at a time, or alternately with a lock from the `java.util.concurrent.locks` package.  Using java.util.concurrent is generally the preferred approach for new programs.

Comment: Your first example doesn't make sense because there is no guarantee of a deterministic single clock relating operations on multiple CPUs. Also, virtually all CPUs in common use guarantee that happens-before isn't violated with respect to a single memory address--you need multiple memory addresses to illustrate the concept effectively. Once you get rid of the broken single-clock idea, you're left with viewing the operations from the perspective of one thread at a time, at which point your example boils down to simple thread interference.

Comment: While everything you've written is correct, I don't think it helps OP with his goal of learning to write a safe java program.  The Java Virtual Machine has its own internal memory model that isolates the program from the nuances of the underlying platform.  The example I gave is the problem that he will actually run into in an improperly written java program, although as you say not strictly fitting a computer engineering definition of a memory consistency issue.

Comment: I suggest you check your understanding of the JVM specification. The JVM does not hide the "nuances" that I was using as examples. The point I'm making is that both of your examples are thread interference. MCE's *must* involve the underlying platform, by definition.

Comment: For whatever arguing on the internet in a week old thread is worth -  That example is the Sun/Oracle tutorial's example of a Memory Consistency problem that the OP referred to in his question.  So I tried to supplement it with some more information to make the difference between the two examples more clear to him.  If the original article is wrong, I guess we should let Oracle know! :)

Answer (score 0):

First, please note, that your source is NOT the best place to learn what you're trying to learn. You will do well reading papers from @blucz 's answer (as well as his answer in general), even if it's out of scope of Java. Oracle Trails aren't *bad* per se, but they simplify matters and gloss over them, hence you may find you don't understand what you've just learned or whether it's useful or not and how much.

Now, trying to answer primarily within Java context.

### Thread interference

happens when thread operations **interleave**, that is, mingle. We need two executors (threads) and shared data (place to interfere).
Image by Daniel Stori, from turnoff.us website:

[image: Daniel Stori, turnoff.us]

In the image you see that two threads in a GNU/Linux process can interfere with each other. Java threads are essentially Java objects pointing to native threads and they also can interfere with each other, if they operate on same data (like here where "Rick" messes up the data - drawing - of his younger brother).

### Memory Consistency Errors - MCE

Crucial points here are memory visibility, happens-before and - brought up by @blucz, hardware.

MCE are - obviously - situations, where memory becomes inconsistent. Which actually is a term for humans - for computers the memory is consistent at all times (unless it's corrupted). The "inconsistencies" are something humans are "seeing", because they don't understand what exactly happened and were expecting something else.  "Why is it 1? It should be 2?!"

This "perceived inconsistency", this "gap", relates to memory *visibility*, that is, what different threads *see* when they *look at* memory. And therefore what those threads *operate on*.
You see, while reads from and writes to memory are linear when we reason about code (especially when thinking about how it is executed line by line)... actually they are not. Especially, when threads are involved. So, the tutorial you read gives you an example of a counter being incremented by two threads and how thread 2 reads same value as thread 1. Actual reasons for memory inconsistencies might be due to optimizations done to your code, by javac, JIT or hardware memory consistency model (that is, something that CPU people did to speed up their CPU and make it more efficient). These optimizations include prescient stores, branch prediction and for now you may think of them as reordering code so that in the end, it runs faster and uses/wastes less CPU cycles. However, to make sure optimizing doesn't go out of control (or too far), some guarantees are made. These guarantees form relationship of "happens-before", where we can tell that before *this point* and after, things "happened-before". Imagine you running a party and remembering, that Tom got here BEFORE Suzie, cause you know that Rob came after tom and before Suzie. Rob is the event which you use to form happens-before relationship before events of Tom/Suzie coming in.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility

Link above tells you more about memory visibility and what establishes happens-before relationship in Java. It will not come as a surprise, but:

1. synchronization does
2. starting a Thread
3. joining a Thread
4. volatile keyword tells you that writes happens-before subsequent reads, that is, that reads AFTER writes will not be reordered to be "before" writes, as that would break "happens-before" relationship.

Since all that touches memory, hardware is essential. Your platform has it's own rules and while JVM tries to make them universal by making all platforms behave similarly, just that alone means that on platform A there will be more memory barriers than on platform B.

### Your questions

> What is the difference between memory consistency errors and thread interference? 
>   MCE are about **visibility** of the memory to program threads and NOT having **happens-before relationship** between reads and writes, therefore having a gap between what humans think "should be" and what "actually is".

Thread interference is about thread operations overlapping, mingling, interleaving and touching shared data, screwing it in the process, that may lead to thread A having nice drawing destroyed by thread B. Interference being harmful usually marks a critical section, which is why synchronization works.

> How does the use of synchronization to avoid them differ or not?

Please read also about thin locks, fat locks and thread contention.
Synchronization to avoid thread interference does it in making only one thread access the critical section, other thread is blocked (costly, thread contention). When it comes to MCE synchronization establishes happens-before when it comes to locking and unlocking the mutex, see earlier link to java.util.concurrent package description.

For examples: see both earlier sections.